# Conditional resolve from promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How can i get true resolve from promise only if the object contains 'four', in all other cases false

P.S. sorry for my english

```js
let asyncForEach = function(object, callback) {
 let p = Promise.resolve();
  for (const item of object) {
   p = p.then(() => item).then(callback);
  }
  return p;
}

let asyncRequest = value => new Promise(resolve => 
 setTimeout(resolve(value), 150));

let object = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

let result = asyncForEach(object, asyncRequest);

result.then(resolve => document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resolve)
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Write an `asyncMap` instead of an `asyncForEach`.

Comment: Thanks for response. What does it give?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that? It seems that this is not a real code. The variable `object` will always have these values?

Comment: Yes, it is not real code, just snippet